# ListView onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I've a ListView (VL) with HListView (HL) as items (bookshelf style). I'm saving the VL state and it's working, but now what I want is to save it's items state because I want the HLs to restore their state when they are rendered again.
So I'm doing something like this in my **BookShelfBaseAdapter**:

```
private List<Book> bookList;
private Parcelable[] bookListStates;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int fPosition = position;
    ...

    holder.booksHListView.setOnScrollListener(new ContentListOnScrollListener(holder) {
       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsHListView view, int scrollState) {}

       @Override
       public void onScroll(AbsHListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
           bookListStates[fPosition] = holder.booksHListView.onSaveInstanceState();
       }
    });

    if (bookListStates[fPosition] != null) {
        holder.booksHListView.onRestoreInstanceState(bookListStates[fPosition]);
    }
    ...
}
```

When the list items are rendered again they aren't in the state they were before... What I'm I doing wrong here?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState are lifecycle methods you should never call them directly. Could you post the complete code of your adapter? Then I will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Why shouldn't I call them to save my list state?

Comment: Because they are lifecycle methods you just should not call them yourself. If you want to persist the data in your ListView you have to persist the datasource of your adapter.

Comment: Don't take me wrong but I think what you said don't make sense. I'm not changing the adapter, the List<Books> it's always the same, what I need is to preserve my "book shelf" last index (Instance State) so when the user scroll down the bookcase, if scrolls back up when getView renders the correct "book shelf" it remembers the shelf index too. So, the only way I can access the InstanceState is by calling the onSaveInstanceState().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, I have to switch the "saving coding" with the "restore code", like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
final int fPosition = position;
...

if (bookListStates[fPosition] != null) {
    holder.booksHListView.onRestoreInstanceState(bookListStates[fPosition]);
}

holder.booksHListView.setOnScrollListener(new ContentListOnScrollListener(holder) {
   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsHListView view, int scrollState) {}

   @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsHListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
       bookListStates[fPosition] = holder.booksHListView.onSaveInstanceState();
   }
});   
...
```

}

It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bookListStates[fPosition] != null) {
    holder.booksHListView.onRestoreInstanceState(bookListStates[fPosition]);
}

holder.booksHListView.setOnScrollListener(new ContentListOnScrollListener(holder) {
   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsHListView view, int scrollState) {}

   @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsHListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int      totalItemCount) {
       bookListStates[fPosition] = holder.booksHListView.onSaveInstanceState();
   }
```